# Error: Missing } inserted. How can I find the problem and resolve it?

Tags: errors

I need help as soon as possible with the following error code on line 15 of my paper. I'm not sure what error it is, and I tried fixing it, but sadly nothing has worked. I've posted line 15 and the following error code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Line 15:

```
&=&\frac{3x^2}{2\sqrt{x^3+1}}\\
```

Error:

```
Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.15   &
        =&\frac{3x^2}{2\sqrt{x^3+1}}\\
```

Comment: This code fragment is correct. Please post a minimal (non-)working compilable example.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As @Bernard said, please add a [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). You might wish to take a look at the discussion in this meta question: [Why does TeX require such elaborate MWE:s](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6255/32888). In particular, [this answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/6260/32888) explains why the actual error isn't always on the line that the error message indicates.

Comment: Welcome! Please use a subject line which describes the issue. Not only does that make your question useful for others, it also makes it easier for people to figure out if they might be able to answer it. That is, something which highlights the nature of the problem is more likely to get you a solution fast than something which merely reports its subjective urgency for you.

Answer (score 2):

The (La)TeX parser is quite fragile, and gets easily confused, sometimes complaining about wildly off reasons. I often see the above, and fix this with emacs' help (it has special commands for the following, can do it by hand too)

- Comment out (parts of) the offending file. Sometimes the error is much earlier than the report. A related idea is to run LaTeX just on parts of the file ("Run LaTeX on region" in emacs).
- Add a close } at the end of the equation, search where it is opened. This usually nets the culprit. If not, move it up and try again. Comment out the pieces you have checked.
- Sometimes the error is in a previous equation environment, commenting out equations until the error disappears helps identifying the culprit.
- Leaving blank lines in equation environments can give strange messages